# Header file not found despite include path listed in makefile

Tags: c, makefile, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile some code that uses the BLIS framework, but it seems that the compiler is throwing errors at `#include "blis.h"` in my C Source File.

I've installed BLIS to `C:\msys64\home\[USERPROFILE]\blis` (where [userprofile] is my name, or `$HOME/blis`) and the test examples successfully compile.  But running "make" with the following makefile (slightly edited from the BLIS-provided example) in a different directory from the examples (`C:\Users\[USERPROFILE]\projects\blis_practice`):

```
BLIS_PREFIX = $(HOME)/blis
BLIS_INC    = $(BLIS_PREFIX)/include/haswell/blis
BLIS_LIB    = $(BLIS_PREFIX)/lib/haswell/libblis.a

OTHER_LIBS  = -lm -fopenmp

CC          = clang
CFLAGS      = -O2 -g -I$(BLIS_INC)
LINKER      = $(CC)

OBJS        = 00level1v.o

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

all: $(OBJS)
    $(LINKER) $(OBJS) $(BLIS_LIB) $(OTHER_LIBS) -o 00level1v.x
```

Throws the following error:

```
clang -O2 -g -I/home/[USERPROFILE]/blis/include/haswell/blis -c 00level1v.c -o 00level1v.o
00level1v.c:36:10: fatal error: 'blis.h' file not found
#include "blis.h"
         ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [Makefile:14: 00level1v.o] Error 1
```

I've confirmed that blis.h is located at `C:\msys64\home\[USERPROFILE]\blis\include\haswell\` and libblis.a is located at `C:\msys64\home\[USERPROFILE]\blis\lib\haswell\`, while `$HOME/blis` links to `C:\msys64\home\[USERPROFILE]\blis`.

I installed BLIS using the following code in MSYS2 MINGW64

```
cd $HOME
git clone https://github.com/flame/blis.git
CC=clang CXX=clang++ AR=llvm-ar AS=llvm-as RANLIB=echo ./configure -t openmp --enable-static --disable-shared auto
make -j5
make install
```

The below is the full code from 00level1v.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "blis.h"

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    double* x;
    double* y;
    double* z;
    double* w;
    double* a;
    double  alpha, beta, gamma;
    dim_t m, n;
    inc_t rs, cs;

    // Initialize some basic constants.
    double zero      = 0.0;
    double one       = 1.0;
    double minus_one = -1.0;


    //
    // This file demonstrates working with vectors and the level-1v
    // operations.
    //


    //
    // Example 1: Create vectors and then broadcast (copy) scalar
    //            values to all elements.
    //

    printf( "\n#\n#  -- Example 1 --\n#\n\n" );

    // Create a few vectors to work with. We make them all of the same length
    // so that we can perform operations between them.
    // NOTE: We've chosen to use row vectors here (1x4) instead of column
    // vectors (4x1) to allow for easier reading of standard output (less
    // scrolling).
    m = 1; n = 4; rs = n; cs = 1;
    x = malloc( m * n * sizeof( double ) );
    y = malloc( m * n * sizeof( double ) );
    z = malloc( m * n * sizeof( double ) );
    w = malloc( m * n * sizeof( double ) );
    a = malloc( m * n * sizeof( double ) );
    
    // Let's initialize some scalars.
    alpha = 2.0;
    beta  = 0.2;
    gamma = 3.0;

    printf( "alpha:\n%4.1f\n\n", alpha );
    printf( "beta:\n%4.1f\n\n", beta );
    printf( "gamma:\n%4.1f\n\n", gamma );
    printf( "\n" );

    bli_dsetv( BLIS_NO_CONJUGATE, n, &one, x, 1 );
    bli_dsetv( BLIS_NO_CONJUGATE, n, &alpha, y, 1 );
    bli_dsetv( BLIS_NO_CONJUGATE, n, &zero, z, 1 );

    // Note that we can use printv or printm to print vectors since vectors
    // are also matrices. We choose to use printm because it honors the
    // orientation of the vector (row or column) when printing, whereas
    // printv always prints vectors as column vectors regardless of their
    // they are 1 x n or n x 1.
    bli_dprintm( "x := 1.0", m, n, x, rs, cs, "%4.1f", "" );
    bli_dprintm( "y := alpha", m, n, y, rs, cs, "%4.1f", "" );
    bli_dprintm( "z := 0.0", m, n, z, rs, cs, "%4.1f", "" );


    //
    // Example 2: Randomize a vector.
    //

    printf( "\n#\n#  -- Example 2 --\n#\n\n" );

    // Set a vector to random values.
    bli_drandv( n, w, 1 );

    bli_dprintm( "x := randv()", m, n, w, rs, cs, "%4.1f", "" );


    //
    // Example 3: Perform various element-wise operations on vectors.
    //

    printf( "\n#\n#  -- Example 3 --\n#\n\n" );

    // Copy a vector.
    bli_dcopyv( BLIS_NO_CONJUGATE, n, w, 1, a, 1 );
    bli_dprintm( "a := w", m, n, a, rs, cs, "%4.1f", "" );

    // Add and subtract vectors.
    bli_daddv( BLIS_NO_CONJUGATE, n, y, 1, a, 1 );
    bli_dprintm( "a := a + y", m, n, a, rs, cs, "%4.1f", "" );

    bli_dsubv( BLIS_NO_CONJUGATE, n, w, 1, a, 1 );
    bli_dprintm( "a := a + w", m, n, a, rs, cs, "%4.1f", "" );

    // Scale a vector (destructive).
    bli_dscalv( BLIS_NO_CONJUGATE, n, &beta, a, 1 );
    bli_dprintm( "a := beta * a", m, n, a, rs, cs, "%4.1f", "" );

    // Scale a vector (non-destructive).
    bli_dscal2v( BLIS_NO_CONJUGATE, n, &gamma, a, 1, z, 1 );
    bli_dprintm( "z := gamma * a", m, n, z, rs, cs, "%4.1f", "" );

    // Scale and accumulate between vectors.
    bli_daxpyv( BLIS_NO_CONJUGATE, n, &alpha, w, 1, x, 1 );
    bli_dprintm( "x := x + alpha * w", m, n, x, rs, cs, "%4.1f", "" );

    bli_dxpbyv( BLIS_NO_CONJUGATE, n, w, 1, &minus_one, x, 1 );
    bli_dprintm( "x := -1.0 * x + w", m, n, x, rs, cs, "%4.1f", "" );

    // Invert a vector element-wise.
    bli_dinvertv( n, y, 1 );
    bli_dprintm( "y := 1 / y", m, n, y, rs, cs, "%4.1f", "" );

    // Swap two vectors.
    bli_dswapv( n, x, 1, y, 1 );
    bli_dprintm( "x (after swapping with y)", m, n, x, rs, cs, "%4.1f", "" );
    bli_dprintm( "y (after swapping with x)", m, n, y, rs, cs, "%4.1f", "" );


    //
    // Example 4: Perform contraction-like operations on vectors.
    //

    printf( "\n#\n#  -- Example 4 --\n#\n\n" );

    // Perform a dot product.
    bli_ddotv( BLIS_NO_CONJUGATE, BLIS_NO_CONJUGATE, n, a, 1, z, 1, &gamma );
    printf( "gamma := a * z (dot product):\n%5.2f\n\n", gamma );

    // Perform an extended dot product.
    bli_ddotxv( BLIS_NO_CONJUGATE, BLIS_NO_CONJUGATE, n, &alpha, a, 1, z, 1, &one, &gamma );
    printf( "gamma := 1.0 * gamma + alpha * a * z (accumulate scaled dot product):\n%5.2f\n\n", gamma );


    // Free the memory obtained via malloc().
    free( x );
    free( y );
    free( z );
    free( w );
    free( a );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So does `/home/[USERPROFILE]/blis/include/haswell/blis/blis.h` exist?

Comment: from inside msys do `ls /home/[USERPROFILE]/blis/include/haswell/blis`, does it exist?

Comment: That was a quick!  I was under the impression that the `blis` component of that was being read as `blis.h` given the `libblis.a` path.  Using `/home/[USERPROFILE]/blis/include/haswell/` as the include path got it working.  Your combined feedback was helpful, so if either of you want to write that out as an answer I can accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to wrap up the question, the issue was in how I wrote my include path.  In the below:

```
BLIS_PREFIX = $(HOME)/blis
BLIS_INC    = $(BLIS_PREFIX)/include/haswell/blis
BLIS_LIB    = $(BLIS_PREFIX)/lib/haswell/libblis.a
```

`BLIS_INC` was directing to a folder in haswell called blis, rather than the header.
It should be changed to:

```
BLIS_PREFIX = $(HOME)/blis
BLIS_INC    = $(BLIS_PREFIX)/include/haswell/
BLIS_LIB    = $(BLIS_PREFIX)/lib/haswell/libblis.a
```

Upon doing so my code compiled properly.